# OpenLayers Vector polygon and jQuery Droppable

Tags: openlayers-2, jquery

How can I use jQuery Droppable to drag and drop an Icon over an openlayers polygon vector and select the polygon while over on hover? I have managed create a create a popup when over a div element, but I can't figure out how to do the same for a polygon inside the "map" div. Hope that makes sense.

[Here is a link to show the concept:](http://jsfiddle.net/Morals/YnWc2/8/)

Update:

Here is a bit of code to show specifically the bit of code I am struggling with. I can currently select a polygon by clicking... but want to select by dropping an icon on the polygon.

```
$(function() {

$( "#cow" ).draggable({ revert: true});
$( "#map" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {

    **\\How do I select a polygon on drop here?**
    alert( "Dropped!" );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I figured out how to use jquery drag and drop to select a polygon.
This assumes you have a select control on the map and activated:

```
 $( "#cow" ).draggable({ revert: true});
    $( "#map" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var farmid = 448; 
    var point = map.getLonLatFromPixel( map.events.getMousePosition(event, ui ) )
    var lon =  point.lon.toFixed(3);
    var lat =   point.lat.toFixed(3);
    var dropPosition = point.lon.toFixed(3) + ' ' + point.lat.toFixed(3);

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../php/position.php", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{'farmid':'"+ farmid +"', 'position':'"+ dropPosition +"'}",
    success: function(returnval){ 

    var pid = parseInt(returnval); 
    var selectB = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([farmbounds]);
    for(var f=0;f<farmbounds.features.length;f++) {
                                    if(farmbounds.features[f].fid == 'farmpaddocks.'+pid+'') {
                                selectB.select(farmbounds.features[f]);
break;
  }}
}//success
});//ajax
}
});
```

And here is the php code:

```
<?php 
$farmid= $_GET["farmid"];
$position = $_GET["position"];
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=postgis user=aaaaa password=bbbbb" ); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM public.farmpaddocks WHERE farmid = '$farmid' AND st_contains(farmpaddocks.the_geom,ST_GeomFromText('POINT($position)',3111)) ='t'";
$resultD = pg_query($db,$sql); 
while($rowD=pg_fetch_row($resultD))  
{ 
$paddockid= $rowD[0];
echo $paddockid;
}

?>
```